# Scala IDE(Eclipse) not picking up the latest code

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, scala-ide

I have just started with scala plugin for Eclipse(Mars)and was able to run some example programs. I then modified one of the programs and tried to run it. Strangely the IDE is still running an older version of code and doesn't reflect the changes I have made recently. I tried refreshing the project, creating a new configuration, restarting Eclipse etc. Nothing seems to be working. No matter how many changes I made it picks the same version every time.

It would be really helpful if someone could provide me some pointers/suggestions to make it work.

**Versions used:**

- Eclipse : Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
- Scala : Fixed Scala Installation: 2.10.6 (bundled)
- OS : OS X El Capitan

Please let me know if you need more details. Thank you so much for your valuable time!

Comment: Did you create the config using the sbt eclipse plugin?

Comment: No. I created it by going to **Scala Application** under the **Run Configuration** menu.